# shell script to create multiple files, incrementing from last file upon next execution

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to create a shell script that will create multiple files (or a batch of files) of a specified amount. When the amount is reached, script stops. When the script is re-executed, the files pick up from the last file created. So if the script creates files 1-10 on first run, then on the next script execution should create 11-20, and so on.

```
enter code here
#!/bin/bash
NAME=XXXX
valid=true
NUMBER=1
while [ $NUMBER -le 5 ];
do
   touch $NAME$NUMBER
   ((NUMBER++))
   echo $NUMBER + "batch created"
   if [ $NUMBER == 5 ];
   then
     break
   fi
   touch $NAME$NUMBER
   ((NUMBER+5))
   echo "batch complete"
done
```

Comment: What do you get with this script, and what do you intend to get?

Comment: Often better for sort order if you use (e.g. `001, 002, ...`) You can use `printf -v num "%03d" "$number"` (avoid ALLCAPS names -- those are for system and shell variables) A loop simply testing for the existence is fine `fname="$name$num"` and then `while [ -e "$fname"' ]; do number=$((number + 1));  printf -v num "%03d" "$number"; fname="$name$num"`. Then on loop exit `touch "$fname"`

Comment: You always set the `NUMBER` to 1 initially, instead of picking up the number where you have ended during the last execution of the script. In addition, your loop will be executed only once, creating file 1 and file 2. After this, NUMBER is 7 and the loop will terminate. For debugging, I suggest that you put a `set -x` in your script and analyze its output.

Comment: @David - the script you provided throws a syntax error when I run it. based upon this script example here enter code here   #!/bin/bash   NAME=XXXX   valid=true NUMBER=1   while [ $NUMBER -le 5 ];   do touch $NAME$NUMBER ((NUMBER++)) echo $NAME$NUMBER + "file created"   done   also I have to use ALLCAPS in my script to run the script. how am I able to output the next sequence of filenames to start at NAME06 and stop at NAME10, and keep incrementing the count when the script is executed each time?

Comment: @Pierre - when I run this script as shown in the original post, I get an output of four files, when I run the script again, it does not create a new batch of files from where the last filename left off.

Comment: Let me catch up to which script you are talking about and which original post. When I hear a script works to create files once, but fails the 2nd time, I thing about either an overwrite or permissions issue. Help me narrow down what we are talking about and I'm happy to help further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my comment above and your description, you can write a script that will create 10 numbered files (by default) each time it is run, starting with the next available number. As mentioned, rather than just use a raw-unpadded number, it's better for general sorting and listing to use zero-padded numbers, e.g. `001`, `002`, ...

If you just use `1`, `2`, ... then you end up with odd sorting when you reach each power of `10`. Consider the first 12 files numbered `1...12` without padding. a general listing sort would produce:

```
file1
file11
file12
file2
file3
file4
...
```

Where `11` and `12` are sorted before `2`. Adding leading zeros with `printf -v` avoids the problem.

Taking that into account, and allowing the user to change the prefix (first part of the file name) by giving it as an argument, and also change the number of new files to create by passing the count as the 2nd argument, you could do something like:

```sh
 #!/bin/bash

prefix="${1:-file_}"                ## beginning of filename
number=1                            ## start number to look for
ext="txt"                           ## file extension to add

newcount="${2:-10}"                 ## count of new files to create

printf -v num "%03d" "$number"      ## create 3-digit start number
fname="$prefix$num.$ext"            ## form first filename

while [ -e "$fname" ]; do           ## while filename exists
  number=$((number + 1))            ## increment number
  printf -v num "%03d" "$number"    ## form 3-digit number
  fname="$prefix$num.$ext"          ## form filename
done

while ((newcount--)); do            ## loop newcount times
  touch "$fname"                    ## create filename
  ((! newcount)) && break;          ## newcount 0, break (optional)
  number=$((number + 1))            ## increment number
  printf -v num "%03d" "$number"    ## form 3-digit number
  fname="$prefix$num.$ext"          ## form filename
done
```

Running the script without arguments will create the first 10 files, `file_001.txt` - `file_010.txt`. Run a second time, it would create 10 more files `file_011.txt` to `file_020.txt`.

To create a new group of 5 files with the prefix of `list_`, you would do:

```
bash scriptname list_ 5
```

Which would result in the 5 files `list_001.txt` to `list_005.txt`. Running again with the same options would create `list_006.txt` to `list_010.txt`.

Since the scheme above with 3 digits is limited to `1000` files max (if you include `000`), there isn't a big need to get the number from the last file written (bash can count to `1000` quite fast). However, if you used 7-digits, for 10 million files, then you would want to parse the last number with `ls -1 | tail -n 1` (or version sort and choose the last file). Something like the following would do:

```sh
  number=$(ls -1 "$prefix"* | tail -n 1 | grep -o '[1-9][0-9]*')
```

(**note:** that is `ls -(one)` not `ls -(ell)`)

Let me know if that is what you are looking for.